# Can html5 'a' attributes be added using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code (Chrome and Firefox only)

HTML:

```
<a id="savefile"">
    Save transferred file
</a>
```

javascript:

```
// event is returned by a readAsDataURL()
var save = document.getElementById('savefile');
save.href = event.target.result;
save.target = '_blank';
save.download = fileName;
```

Besides the first line, is line 2, 3 and 4 possible in jQuery?
I understand this is a non-space saving question - however It's in the middle of a jQuery subject tutorial I'm trying to compose on dataBlobs and browser compatibility.

I've been looking for about an hour - have had no luck finding the info, 'download' being the worlds worst keyword.

Comment: Yes they are all possible.

Comment: Since you know those are attributes, why not just use `attr()` to add them? (But really, it's entirely acceptable to set them the way you are doing already and then wrap the element object in a jQuery object.)

Comment: `$("#savefile").attr( { "href" : event.target.result, "target" : "_blank", "download" : filename } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all those attributes using one call to `attr()`:

```
$("#savefile").attr(
    {
        "href" : event.target.result,
        "target" : "_blank",
        "download" : filename
    }
);
```

Official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I thought it might be attribute, but was lacking examples., I should have hit the jquery docs! thanks

Comment: Confirmed in the latest Chrome and FF. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = $("#savefile")
elem.attr( "attribute-name" , "attribute-value" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can add attributes to any element you can select.

See documentation [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Example usage

```
$("#savefile").attr("target", "_blank");
```